# get_posts $args won't accept array as one of the criteria?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, get-posts

The goal is to list attachments underneath a WooCommerce product, using the tags from that product. Everything works fine if I manually enter the tags at `'product_tag'`, but when I try to use an array `$producttags`, why doesn't it work?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'precon_drawing_attachments' );
function precon_drawing_attachments() {
    $productterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );
    $producttags = array();
    foreach ( $productterms as $productterm ) {
        $producttags[] = $productterm->name;
    }
    $args = array(
        'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'product_tag'    => array( $producttags ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'post_parent'    => null );
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        echo '<div class="drawings-list">';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
            echo '<li class="drawing-li">';
            echo '<img class="drawing-icon" src="';
            bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );
            echo '/images/Adobe_PDF_file_icon_32x32.png"';
            echo ' />';
            echo '<span class="drawing-link">';
            echo the_attachment_link( $post->ID, false );
            echo '</span>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `'product_tag' => array( $producttags ),`

`$producttags` is already an array, so in this case it gets nested into a sub array. Change your arg to the following instead:

`'product_tag' => $producttags,`

Comment: Thanks @jzatt That seems to have done it. I changed `$producttags[]` to `$producttagnames[]` and then `'product_tag'    => array( $producttags ),` to `'product_tag' => $producttagnames,`. All is working.